# Finding out increasing or decreasing monotonic array in java

Tags: java, arrays, sortedlist

This is an interview question.

Find out if an input array to a method is increasing order or decreasing order. Ties will go with the current order. I mean if other members are increasing and some of them or equal its fine, and the same is true for decreasing elements. The function returns true or false.

I have done it this way. I am thinking if there is another but creative way to do it.

```
boolean isMonotonic(int[] arr){
    if(arr.length <= 2){
        return true;
    }
    boolean increasing = true;
    boolean decreasing = true;
    for (int i=1; i<arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[i-1] > arr[i]){
            increasing = false;
        } else if(arr[i-1] < arr[i]){
            decreasing = false;
        }
        if (!increasing && !decreasing){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your solution is clean, makes just a single pass down the array, and I'm not sure it could be done mucb more elegantly.  Another way to phrase that increasing haa switched to decreasing would be to keep track of the previous and second to previous move.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is very good, fast and efficient.

The important is you loop the array only once, so your complexity is linear **O(n)** and there is not any more efficient solution than this. However, it is necessary to change it slightly to make it work.  Whenever you multiply by 0 as you do, the answer is always 0.  So you must change the initialization to = 1 not 0.

Yeah, you can use the Collections that Java offers in sake of saving more lines or making it a bit more readable, but why? Personally, I think you provided a clean solution to this issue and there is no reason to refactor the solution in the case it's smart, easy and efficient. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will be more efficient. But we can calculate the difference between neighbor elements. If the diff is constantly negative or 0 - the sequence is decreasing. If it is positive or 0 - it is increasing. We have to detect the point where diff changes it's sign. To avoid "if" statements we can use multiplication. In monotonic sequence two diffs multiplication will always be positive or 0.

```
static boolean isMonotonic(int[] arr){
    if(arr.length <= 2){
        return true;
    }
    int diff = 0;
    for (int i=1; i<arr.length; i++){
        int newDiff = arr[i] - arr[i-1];
        if (newDiff * diff < 0) {
            return false;
        }
        diff = newDiff;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You are right, but the solution will still be O(n), so I think its similar.